# Google Analytics "There was an internal error"

Tags: error-handling, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

Recent days I am getting "There was an internal error" error message from Google while calling Google Analytics API to get reports data. Previously the same API works fine. Following are the dimensions and metrics we used,

**dimensions** : ga:campaign,ga:adGroup,ga:keyword,ga:adContent,ga:date
**metrics**    : ga:sessions,ga:bounces,ga:impressions,ga:adClicks,ga:adCost,ga:transactions,ga:RPC

When I remove the metrics parameter it's working fine. Can't figure out why this metrics   value causes problem. Below is the full error message which I am facing

> {
>   "error":{
>   "errors":[
>   {
>   "domain":"global",
>   "reason":"internalError",
>   "message":"There was an internal error."
>   }
>   ],
>   "code":500,
>   "message":"There was an internal error."
>   }
>   }

Comment: what happens if you send the same request again?  I normally do a retry on this error.  IMO its a server hiccup   Can you post your code?

Comment: I tried many times it's showing the same error. I am using Analytics rest API https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga .

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: For a particular account only I got this kind of error. After few days it was working again. Can't figure out the issue. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 17):

I just encountered the same issue - it turns out that my adblocking extension (uBlock Origin) was interfering with the page. Disabling it resolved the error.

Comment: suffered from this for months, and this solves my issue.